# cron failing for python: Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec

Tags: python, cron, virtualenv

I have a python script and a virtualenv for it. Suppose the script just prints.

```
print('Testing')
```

And I want to schedule a cron job.

```
* * * * * cd /Users/irmaz/Desktop/projects/fit && fit/bin/python fit.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
```

the cron.log file shows the errors:

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00000001164fbdc0 (most recent call first):
```

I've tried just specifying the virtualenv python with an absolute path but that doesn't seem to work either.  Any idea what is going on ?

Comment: Set absolute paths for `python` and the log

Comment: Tried anything from the search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+Fatal+Python+error%3A+initfsencoding%3A+unable+to+load+the+file+system+codec ?